# How to get rid of dry marker stains from your clothes

Tags: cleaning, clothing

I have ruined so many good clothing it is really bothering me.

I have tried 
https://home.howstuffworks.com/home-improvement/household-hints-tips/cleaning-organizing/how-to-get-dry-erase-marker-out-of-clothes.htm

I have tried a lot of different products. They either discolor the fabric or they just don't work.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to [cseducators.se]!  I'm afraid that I have to close this question as off-topic for our site, which is about how to teach Computer Science specifically.  Sorry to hear about your issue, and good luck with your stains!

Comment: If you specified clearly how this related to being an Academic the question might be on topic in academia.se

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marker ink is usually alcohol based. But I admit that I am not sure about dry erase. If you go to the store and get a can of denatured alcohol, if it is going to work the stains should come right out without hardly any scrubbing at all. Just pour it on. I don't think the alcohol will ever affect your fabric either, but don't sue me.

On the other hand, you may regret throwing out any of your old stuff if it works as good as I think it might.

Comment: Appreciated, any bleach related solution has always ruined my clothes.

Answer (score 0):

Bleach works well for a variety of stains by breaking down the chemical bonds that give the ink its colour properties. It can cause yellowing of son fabrics though, so use dilute first in an inconspicuous area

Might it be a better idea to keep the dry erase markers somewhere other than in your pocket?